# Bash While loops

Tags: bash, wget

I have a loop set up like the following

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1|while read line;do
    wget --limit-rate=50k http://url/$line.json -O got-$line;
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
        rm got-$line;
    fi
    sleep 4;
done
```

But when i call it

./script inputfile.txt

I get the following error

```
rm: cannot remove `got-inputfile.txt': No such file or directory
--2012-12-30 12:18:06--  (start of wget output and everything works normal)
```

Like the loop is running before there is any input

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The first line goes to `stderr` and the next to `stdout`. These are buffered and order is not guaranteed.

Comment: it doesn't happen when $1 is replaced with the actual file name. so does the stderr line only occur when a variable file is used ?

Comment: run it with `-x` - either put `set -x` into the script or run as `bash -x script ...` and check the `stderr` for what is really happening.

Comment: Already mentioned quote the URL (with double quotes you don't need to change anything else) I would also change the logic to `if ! wget ...; then`. Slightly shorter and possibly easier to read...

Answer (score 3):

I suspect `url` actually contains a `&` which causes the `wget` command to be run in background. You'd need to quote that *url*.